# Assembly only referenced through typeof(TypeInAssembly) in attribute is not listed as reference by GetReferencedAssemblies()

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-assembly, roslyn

**tl;dr**: [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't seem to include assemblies referenced only through types used in attributes with `typeof(...)`, e.g. `[SomeAttribute(typeof(TypeInAssembly))]` when built with MSBuild through Visual Studio 2013 and earlier, but *does* when built with Roslyn in Visual Studio 2015.

This happens for .NET 4.0, 4.5, and 4.6 and seems to be a bug(?) in MSBuild. Is there any way to *reliably* get all the assemblies referenced by another assembly including those only referenced through `typeof` in attributes?

---

### An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem

Reproducing this is trivial: reference the `PresentationCore` assembly in a blank C# console application project and use the following code<sup>1, 2, 3, 4</sup>:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

[ReferenceTypeAttribute(typeof(DurationConverter))]
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // uncomment the following two lines to change the results of GetReferencedAssemblies().
        //Console.WriteLine("DurationConverter assembly from typeof:");
        //showAssemblyNameDetails(typeof(DurationConverter).Assembly.GetName());

        AssemblyName[] referenced = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Referenced Assemblies:");
        foreach ( AssemblyName reference in referenced )
            showAssemblyNameDetails(reference);

        var referenceTypeAttribute = (ReferenceTypeAttribute)typeof(Program)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ReferenceTypeAttribute), inherit: false)[0];
        AssemblyName presentationCoreAssemblyName = referenceTypeAttribute.Type.Assembly.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "DurationConverter Assembly from attribute:");
        showAssemblyNameDetails(presentationCoreAssemblyName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void showAssemblyNameDetails(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Version);
    }
}
```

where the definition of `ReferenceTypeAttribute` is:

```cs
public class ReferenceTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public readonly Type Type;

    public ReferenceTypeAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> For brevity I've done away with the `namespace` and put everything in `Main`.

<sup>2</sup> I chose [`DurationConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.durationconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) because it's in an assembly which isn't added to a C# project by default (`PresentationCore`). The same is true for *every* type I've tried this with.

<sup>3</sup> I explicitly wrote my own attribute for this rather than using [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which is the attribute actually used in my code) to eliminate any doubt that .NET is doing something funky during compilation.

<sup>4</sup> Changing the attribute to take an `object`, then casting the `object` back to a `Type` has no effect - this indicates that the issue is due to `typeof`.

### My question

I'm aware that assemblies which are referenced but not used aren't included in the result of `GetReferencedAssemblies()`, but *why* doesn't being used in an attribute count? I can only assume that this is a bug in MSBuild which has been fixed in Roslyn, but I cannot find any reference to this.

I need to have reliable results for `GetReferencedAssemblies()` but don't want to have to put explicit references in as hacks; either by referencing the type in the code *outside* of an attribute, or some other means.

---

### Full Results (Visual Studio 2013)

- Running the code as it is, the output is:

> ```
> Referenced Assemblies:
> mscorlib (4.0.0.0)
>
> DurationConverter Assembly:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
> ```

This is reflected by looking at the assembly with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net):

[image: just mscorlib]

Note that `PresentationCore` is **not** listed as a referenced assembly even though it's referenced through the attribute on the class, and the solution won't build *without* the reference.

Note also that this is not affected by changing the target framework - I've tried .NET 4.0, 4.5, and 4.6 but the results are the same.

- Only by uncommenting the first two lines of code in `Main` is the reference to `PresentationCore` picked up by `GetReferencedAssemblies`:

> ```
> DurationConverter assembly from typeof:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
>
> Referenced Assemblies:
> mscorlib (4.0.0.0)
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
>
> DurationConverter Assembly from attribute:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
> ```

Again, this is reflected by looking at the assembly with ILSpy:

[image: with PresentationCore]

### Full Results (Visual Studio 2015)

- The reference to `PresentationCore` picked up by `GetReferencedAssemblies` even when the lines are commented out:

> ```
> Referenced Assemblies:
> mscorlib (4.0.0.0)
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
>
> DurationConverter Assembly from attribute:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
> ```

ILSpy agrees:

[image: with PresentationCore]

- As expected, uncommmenting the first two lines doesn't change the result of `GetReferencedAssemblies`:

> ```
> DurationConverter assembly from typeof:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
>
> Referenced Assemblies:
> mscorlib (4.0.0.0)
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
>
> DurationConverter Assembly from attribute:
> PresentationCore (4.0.0.0)
> ```

Again, ILSpy agrees:

[image: with PresentationCore]

Comment: Did you eleminate the possibility that this a problem in ILSpy? Can you verify your results with [ILDasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: It is nice when a compiler emits `.assembly` directives in the assembly metadata, but it is not required.  Attribute constructor arguments are rather special, easy to see how the old compiler could have failed to emit the directive.  A bug.  Fixing such a bug is quite risky, Roslyn was an excellent opportunity.

Comment: @thehennyy - thanks for the suggestion - the same behaviour is seen when I view the manifest in ILDasm or [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks for your comment. Do you happen to have a link to somewhere I can read about the bug? I've done a bit of searching and haven't found references to it.

Comment: This is not a well-known problem.  So sure, unlikely you'll anything about it.  When programmers use ReferencedAssemblies they only ever care about types, never about attribute constructor data.